# Rank-1 convexity is equivalent to the Legendre-Hadamard condition for a twice continuously differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis

**Problem :** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a twice continuously differentiable function and rank-$1$ convex function. Prove that $$\sum\limits_{i,j,k,l=1}^{2}\frac{\partial^2f(\xi)}{\partial\xi_{ij}\partial\xi_{kl}}\lambda_{i}\lambda_{k}\mu_{j}\mu_{l}\ge0$$ for every $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{R^2}$, $\xi=(\xi_{ij})_{1\leq i,j\leq2}\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$. That is, the rank-$1$ convexity is equivalent to the Legendre-Hadamard condition.

I know that we have to set $\phi(t)=f(\xi+t\lambda\otimes\mu)$, where $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$, $\mu=(\mu_1,\mu_2)$ and $\lambda\otimes\mu=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1\mu_1 & \lambda_1\mu_2\\
\lambda_2\mu_1 & \lambda_2\mu_2 \end{pmatrix}$ and use the convexity of $\phi$ to deduce the required inequality, that is $\phi^{\prime\prime}(t)\ge0$ but I am struggling to bring it in the required form. Also, how can I show that the converse is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the chain rule, we have:
$$\phi'(t)=\sum_{k,l=1}^2\frac{\partial f}{\partial\xi_{kl}}(\xi+t\lambda\otimes\mu)\lambda_k\mu_l,$$
$$\phi''(t)=\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\xi_{ij}\partial\xi_{kl}}(\xi+t\lambda\otimes\mu)\lambda_i\lambda_k\mu_j\mu_l.$$
Setting $t:=0$, we obtain the Legendre-Hadamard condition, since $\phi''(0)\geq 0$ by the rank-1 convexity of $f$.
Conversely, if the L.-H. condition is satisfied at $\xi\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$, then $\phi''(0)\geq 0$ (with any choice of $\lambda$ and $\mu$), hence $f$ is rank-1 convex at $\xi$. This can be done for any $\xi$, so $f$ is rank-1 convex.